# Sort column in pandas dataframe after rarity of values within groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe of scraped websites with a website identifier, a text and a label of the websites. A small number of websites have two labels, but since I want to train first a single label classifier, I would like to create a version of the data with only one label for every website (I'm aware that this is slightly problematic). The labels in my dataset are unbalanced (with some labels occurring very often and some being very rare). If I delete duplicate website IDs, I would like to delete labels that are very common first. This is how my dataset with several labels looks like:

```
ID   Label   Text
1    a       some text
1    b       other text
1    a       data
2    a       words
2    c       more words
3    a       text
3    b       short text
```

My idea was to sort the label column within every website identifier by rarity of the label. For that I would first do `value_counts(ascending = True)` on the label column, to get a list of all labels sorted by rarity.

```
to_sort = [c, b, a]
```

I then would like to use that list to sort within every website ID by rarity. I'm not sure how to do that, though. The result should look like this:

```
ID   Label   Text
1    b       other text
1    a       some text
1    a       data
2    c       more words
2    a       words
3    b       short text
3    a       text
```

I then would use `df.drop_duplicates(subset = 'ID', keep = 'first')`, to keep the label that is the most rare. How can I do the sorting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ordered [`categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html), so possible use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
to_sort = list('cba')

df['Label'] = pd.Categorical(df['Label'], ordered=True, categories=to_sort)

df = df.sort_values(['ID','Label'])
print (df)
   ID Label        Text
1   1     b  other text
0   1     a   some text
2   1     a        data
4   2     c  more words
3   2     a       words
6   3     b  short text
5   3     a        text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal by making the Label Column **Categorical**, then sort by **ID** and **Label** . Let's see it in practice.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( {'ID': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3], "Label": ["a", "b", "a", "a", "c", "a", "b"],
                   'Text': ["some text", "other text","data", "words", "more words", "text", "short text"]} )
df
    ID  Label   Text
0   1   a   some text
1   1   b   other text
2   1   a   data
3   2   a   words
4   2   c   more words
5   3   a   text
6   3   b   short text
```

Define your labels' order by doing :

```
to_sort = df.Label.value_counts(ascending = True).index
to_sort
Index(['c', 'b', 'a'], dtype='object')
```

Then make the **Label** column **Categorical** like this :

```
df.Label = pd.Categorical(df.Label,categories = to_sort, ordered = True)
```

Finally, sort by **ID** and **Label** :

```
df.sort_values(["ID", "Label"]).reset_index(drop = True)

    ID  Label   Text
0   1   b   other text
1   1   a   some text
2   1   a   data
3   2   c   more words
4   2   a   words
5   3   b   short text
6   3   a   text
```

Comment: So why you post your answer? OP know `df.Label.value_counts(ascending = True).index` and `.reset_index(drop = True)` is only small difference with my answer :(

Comment: I wrote mine independently and only saw yours after posting mine. I avoid, however, to delete it because it is more detailed.